# angular.forEach returning array of objects repeats the same object

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs, loops

I have an array of 5 objects that i need to loop through and return in an array of objects. However when i do that, it only returns the last object 5 times.

I've got two pieces of code doing pretty much the exact same thing one works where as another doesn't.

working code: (loops through a string, splits on | and returns an object in an array);

```
angular.forEach(exampleString, function(data) {
    if (data.indexOf('|') !== -1) {
        data = data.split('|');
        //self.model.getDataFromArray()returns an object
        newArray.push(new self.model.getDataFromArray(data));
    }
});
```

`//returns array of objects`

doesn't work: (loops through objects and returns an object but only pushes the last 1 to the array 5 times)

```
angular.forEach(exampleObjects, function(data) {
    this.push(new self.model.getDataFromObject(data));
}, newArray);
```

Is there anything that i'm doing or not doing that is causing this to fail? the only real difference i can tell is that i start with a string that i split as opposed to starting with an object.

just to clarify if i do the following i get the same repetition:

```
 angular.forEach(exampleObjects, function(data) {
    newArray.push(new self.model.getDataFromObject(data));
});
```

Comment: is the exampleString a string? or is it an array?? Your assessment "loops through a string" is incorrect, the first parameter of your foreach is supposed to be an object/array you iterate over. You don't iterate over a string value.

Comment: @sksallaj sorry yeah, it's an array of strings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the problem lays in your getDataFromObject method. What is the code in that method?

Comment: `getDataFromObject(data) {
    var obj = {};
    obj = data;
    obj.attr1 = data.attr1;
    obj.attr2 = data.attr2;
    return obj;
}`

just simple mapping, exactly the same as the other working method

Comment: what seemed to work for me was changing var `obj = {};` to `self.obj = {};` not sure why it makes a difference